# How do I display multiple lines in a SwiftUI Text view which is in a Form Section?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to display a long string of text in a Text view within a Section within a Form, but the text keeps getting cut off after the first line with an ellipse (...). I have tried both `Text("Text here").lineLimit(10)` and `Text("Text here").lineLimit(nil)` but neither seem to work.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NoteInfo: View {

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Form {
        Section {
          Text("Hello world we have a very long string that will be truncated here")
            .lineLimit(10)
        }

      }
      .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Note Info"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It might be that this is a bug or limitation of the current beta (Xcode beta 7 currently) as I see similar behaviour in Lists, and ScrollView VStack views.

Comment: @KB-YYZ Ah, I was not aware of this being a bug, thank you. I'll wait for the next beta and update or delete this question if it's fixed.

Answer (score 6):

it not a bug, try

```
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

Comment: That seems to work! I wonder why this is not the default configuration for Text...

Comment: you might find some explanation in https://netsplit.com/swiftui/flexible-frames/ and https://netsplit.com/swiftui/views-have-fixed-sizes/

Comment: I spent more than a day on this!! This is the only thing that worked. THANK YOU!